# Wrapping InputStream to non blocking ReadableByteChannel

Tags: java, nio

Is it possible to create non blocking ReadableByteChannel from InputStream object?

Channel.newChannel(inputStream) - produces channel which could be blocked by blocked InputStream.read invocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newInputStream-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-).

Comment: But maybe some libraries exists?

Comment: No, it is not possible, see the Javadoc. No library can make impossible things possible.

Comment: It is possible, just not advisable. It could be done at the expense of a `Thread` to pipe the blocking input to a non-blocking channel, but obviously that would defeat the motivating purpose of non-blocking io (i.e avoiding threads).

Answer (score 1):

You may try to implement such a channel yourself, using 'Inputstream.avalable()' to avoid blocking. However, this method does not guarantee to return correct value, so you have to check the Inputstream implementation you use.

Are you sure you need non-blocking channel? Generally, it requires periodical polling to check arrival of data. Asynchronous channels, which invoke callbacks on data arrival, have more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The ReadableByteChannel.newChannel method

```
public static ReadableByteChannel newChannel(final InputStream in) {
    checkNotNull(in, "in");

    if (in instanceof FileInputStream &&
        FileInputStream.class.equals(in.getClass())) {
        return ((FileInputStream)in).getChannel();
    }

    return new ReadableByteChannelImpl(in);
}
```

and the read method of ReadableByteChannelImpl

```
public int read(ByteBuffer dst) throws IOException {
    int len = dst.remaining();
    int totalRead = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    synchronized (readLock) {
        while (totalRead < len) {
            int bytesToRead = Math.min((len - totalRead),
                                       TRANSFER_SIZE);
            if (buf.length < bytesToRead)
                buf = new byte[bytesToRead];
            if ((totalRead > 0) && !(in.available() > 0))
                break; // block at most once
            try {
                begin();
                bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, bytesToRead);
            } finally {
                end(bytesRead > 0);
            }
            if (bytesRead < 0)
                break;
            else
                totalRead += bytesRead;
            dst.put(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        if ((bytesRead < 0) && (totalRead == 0))
            return -1;

        return totalRead;
    }
}
```

so, it's just calling the read method of the InputStream, and the javadoc of the Inputstream's read method:

> This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is
>   detected, or an exception is thrown.

so you can implements a subclass of InputStream and override the read methods, and implement the methods as nonblocking.

Comment: 'Implement the methods as non-blocking' how?